# Do we know any estimate of how many Sinclair ZX Spectrums, clones, and compatibles were made in the world?

Tags: history, zx-spectrum, zx-spectrum-clones

The original ZX Spectrum was made by Sinclair and then by Amstrad in the UK.

There were official versions also in the US, Europe and even India.

There were very many clones and compatibles made in Russia and Eastern Europe, but also in South America and even in Korea.

There was even the Sam Coupe made in the UK.

Has anybody attempted to estimate how many were manufactured of all these official, clone, and compatible computers?

I'm interested in the pre-retro era, which I suppose lasted up until the late '90s. But in the retro-era the machines have only been in quite small quantities so they probably wouldn't affect the estimate very much anyway.

In particular I'm wondering how the impact of the Spectrum rates overall compared to the Commodore 64, which wasn't cloned very much, and the Apple ][, which was also widely cloned, but I know less about that.

In world terms before the PC era in world terms it seems the humble Speccy played a much bigger part than Sinclair's own production numbers would suggest. Has anybody tried to roughly quantify the overall worldwide numbers?

Comment: With all the unofficial clones in the former eastern Bloc, latin american clones and homemade hardware...this question is  quite vast. Timex TC 2068/2048 in Portugal and Poland, TS 2048/2068 in the Americas, TK95 and TK90X in Brazil...some of the clones where they speak my mother tongue. Now for quantifying NUMBERS, that is nearly impossible.

Comment: Homemade ones are definitely impossible to quantify. Are you nearly positive there are no production numbers available otherwise? How so? I can be confident I don't know, I can't be confident nobody knows without some information to support it.

Comment: I think we do not even know how much Timex computers were really manufactured in Portugal, because (1) the company folded too long ago and (2) corporate tax evasion has always been a national sport.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Well I made it clear I'm only expecting an estimate so it's not necessary to know how many were really made. How many were officially made would suffice. Wikipedia says "more than 10000 units" which will do.